# Decimal places in SQLite

Tags: qgis, area, expression, sqlite

I'm working with a locally stored SQLite database and have an area field that auto populates via a virtual field using $area. Works fine but there seems to be no way to set the precision in a decimal number when using SQLite. Therefore results are not rounded off to the two decimals places I'd really like. I'm wondering if there is something I could add to the expression to do this? Or is it a constraint in an SQLite dbase?

Comment: `Or is it a constraint in an sqlite dbase?` I think it's a feature of sqlite, you can't set the size of the fields, even the data types are flexible see ~ https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html.

Comment: I guess that you can chain the round function of QGIS and $area.

Comment: I figured it was a constraint of sqlite.                                                                        I don't understand "chain the round function of QGIS and $area"

Comment: I mean to round the result of $area. I am not sure about the syntax but the idea is like `round( $area,2)`. You can also round values in SQLite with the native SQL function https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round

Comment: All right, round function updates numbers into for example 14.2600000 which is not exactly what you want to get.

Comment: Actually that's doing exactly what I want thank you!